# why sometime a function return a const, or const reference

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

First, why return const?
say I have

```
friend const MyVec operator-(const MyVec& left, const MyVec& right)
```

so is returning const makes me cannot do:

```
mva - mvb = mvc;
```

Second, why return const reference?
if there is:

```
friend const MyVec& operator++(MyVec& v)
```

with const I cannot: `(++mva) = mvc`

if it is

`MyVec& operator++(MyVec& v)`

I can:`++(++mva)` // with increment twice.

am I understanding right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not any good reason to return a const object. However, there are many good reasons to return pointers or references to const objects.

The program might have an object that is very expensive to copy, so it returns a reference. However, the object should not be changed through that reference. For example, it might be part of a sorted data structure and if its values were modified it would no longer be sorted correctly. So the const keeps it from being modified accidentally.

Arithmetic operator functions should not return const objects, because of exactly the problems in your question.

Dereferencing an iterator should return a const reference. That is if it is operating on a collection of const objects or possibly on a const collection. This is why class functions sometimes have two copies of a function with the second copy using a const on the function itself, like this:

```
T& operator[](size_t index);
const T& operator[](size_t index) const;
```

The first function would be used on non-const objects and the second function would be used for const objects.

Comment: "sometimes operator++ used on an iterator should return a const reference" No. It should not. Because everyone expects `++(++obj)` expression to be valid. The most usable way of defining prefix ++ operator is `T& T::operator++() {...}` and there is no good reason to define it otherwise. May be you mistyped something? May be you mean `operator[]` as in your example?

Comment: "There is not any good reason to return a const object" Yes there is, see Effective C++ item 21. To prevent constructs like (a * b) = c

Comment: "Arithmetic operator functions should not return const objects" : Assuming you mean - and + etc. Yes they should : see Effective C++ and http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html

Comment: @rve : 'Effective C++', while excellent in general, predates C++11; if a new edition came out now, I'd warrant that that advice would be removed, as it disables automatic move semantics in C++11. So, to rephrase: *In modern C++*, there is **not** any good reason to return a const object.

Comment: @rve Just do not write such crap like (a*b)=c, you know what it's doing and if you do not want that behaviour, just don't write it. Do we have to take everybody by the hand?

Comment: @Serge: You are correct and I have fixed the answer. I don't know what I was thinking there.

Comment: @ChristianRau: `if((a*b)==c)` vs `if((a*b)=c)` - it's not about knowing not to do it, it's about not doing it by mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Yes your understanding is correct. **To avoid accidental assignments**, one can return an object by `const` or `const reference`.

With `operator -`, you return an object by value. To avoid it getting edited accidently,  one can return by `const` value, because anyways the object will be mostly a temporary.

For `operator ++`, conventionally it returns reference, however to avoid situations as `(++ x) = y;` you can return it by `const` reference.

Comment: Returning a const value makes automatic move semantics impossible when compiling with a C++11 compiler; it's really just terrible advice.

Comment: @ildjarn, may be. But I was not advising :). It's answer to what he asked. Either questioner is not using C++11 or is aware of those implications.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to imply that you were advising to return `const` values; I only meant to say that it's bad advice in general in the advent of C++11. :-]